# MongoDB cloneCollection between Azure hosted CentOS servers times out at 2 hours

Tags: linux, centos, tcp, mongodb, azure

I'm trying to clone a MongoDB collection from CentOS server A to CentOS server B. Both are running 2.4.6. The copy works great until exaxctly 2 hours, at which point I get a 9001 socket exception: "errno:10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."

I have tried to set the tcp_keepalive_time to 3600, down from 7200 (2 hours) on both servers with the hope that my keep alive probes will tell routers to keep my connection alive after the 1 hour mark.

No dice. Even with a shorter keepalive time (and 70 second interval for keepalive probes), my connection dies at 2 hours.

Does anyone know how to set up my servers and/or my mongodb configuration to allow my tcp connection to be active past 2 hours?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is not a firewall or a script of some kind (such as long running processes) that is killing this connection off?   What about establishing a test connection such as executing a script that does a very long sleep() and see if that sustains.

Trying to narrow down the problem would be what I would do first.